# vimrc commands not applying with cygwin and cscope combination on windows 7

Tags: vim, cygwin, cscope

I have installed cygwin and cscope on my windows 7 machine. I created a .vimrc file in $HOME directory with the following settings:

`syntax on
set hlsearch
set ic`

When i ran cscope, selected a file and tried to find some text, it is not highlighting(it get highlighted when using vim/vi on individual file).

I added "alias vi=vim" too in my $HOME/.bashrc file.

Please help me resolving this and understanding why it is happening, as i think cscope should open files using vi/vim.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the `:scriptnames` command which `~/.vimrc` configuration and plugin files are loaded.

Comment: Thanks Ingo for replying. It is using ~/.vimrc

Comment: So why is the configuration not active? Check with `:verbose set hlsearch?`.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that csope is going to use your alias. It's probably using the EDITOR or VISUAL environment variables. Make sure those are set to /usr/bin/vim and not /usr/bin/vi. On Cygwin, `vi` and `vim` are two different executables. `vi` is configured to be mostly vi-compatible, while `vim` has most of the vim features turned on.